# Tabindex in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, tabindex

I have written a directive which produces a table including some rows. Each row has some drop-down list for selection and also some normal text areas to fill information. 
The problem is, when I hit the tab key on Keyboard, the drop-down selections are ignored and not focused. The cursor jumps to the next text area. I tried to fix the problem with incremental **tabindex** attribute inside each column of rows, but still no difference. 
Each column of each row is produced inside the directive by looping over an array using ng-repeat. Following produces a drop-down:

```
<td><ng-select ng-model="oneRow.XItem" ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in selections.XItemList| orderBy:'name'" cs-option-init=""></ng-select></td>
```

Follwing produces a text area which is focused by pressing tab on keyboard.

```
  <td><ng-input ng-model="oneRow.YItem" ></ng-input></td>
```

Please note all produced inside a directive NOT a static HTML.
The picture depicts the table. By hitting tab key, cursor jumps to next possible text area either in the same row or next row. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Not precisely sure what behavior you are describing here.  However, by default your HTML will tab through properly formatted for fields from left-to-right before continuing to the next row.

Tab will allow the user to focus on the "next " form field, however, once a drop-down has focus, the arrow-up/down keys are used to select an option.  Once an option is selected, pressing tab again moves to the next form field.

If something is skipped, I would check your HTML syntax.

Even via angular, the DOM is the DOM.  If the syntax for your form fields is correct within the table, it will process correctly using tabs.

Non-anglar example because using angular should have zero effect on tabbing if you didn't force a tabindex:  https://codepen.io/KarsunJason/pen/KqeOYg

```
<form>
<table style="width:75%">
  <tr>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere0"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></td>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere1"><option value="volvo">mr</option><option value="saab">mrs</option><option value="mercedes">Sir</option><option value="audi">Madame</option>
</select></td>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere2"><option value="volvo">1</option><option value="saab">2</option><option value="mercedes">3</option><option value="audi">4</option>
</select></td>
    <td><input id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere4"></td>
    <td><input id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere5"></td>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere6"><option value="volvo">5555</option><option value="saab">4444</option><option value="mercedes">3333</option><option value="audi">2222</option>
</select></td>
    <td><input id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere7"></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere8"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select></td>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere9"><option value="volvo">mr</option><option value="saab">mrs</option><option value="mercedes">Sir</option><option value="audi">Madame</option>
</select></td>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere10"><option value="volvo">1</option><option value="saab">2</option><option value="mercedes">3</option><option value="audi">4</option>
</select></td>
    <td><input id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere11"></td>
    <td><input id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere12"></td>
    <td><select id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere13"><option value="volvo">5555</option><option value="saab">4444</option><option value="mercedes">3333</option><option value="audi">2222</option>
</select></td>
    <td><input id="tableDropdown-useNgRepeatIndexHere14"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Suggestions:
1) Check your form fields for proper syntax.
2) Either use tabindex="0" in each field (forces a tab stop within the natural order of the page) or remove tabindex entirely.